# why can't we use BlocProvider.of(blocContext) inside of Consumer with bloc attribute? and what is the solution?

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

inside of a build method:

```
  return BlocBuilder<UserCubit, UserState>(
    bloc: UserCubit("firstName", "lastName"),
    builder: (BuildContext blocContext, UserState state) {
                  print(BlocProvider.of<UserCubit>(blocContext).user.fullName);  // error here
});
```

error:

```
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a UserCubit.
```

which is obviously not the case...

the question is, how can I access the cubit in case of `BlocBuilder/BlocConsumer` where `bloc` attribute is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it is because the widget `BlocBuilder` is not injecting the provided `bloc` parameter in your `BuildContext blocContext`.

The [flutter_bloc documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html) says that that `BlocBuilder` is working like a `StreamBuilder`, it is not injecting anything in your widget tree it will only "listen" to your provided `UserCubit` in the `bloc` property. And because `UserCubit` is not injected in your widget tree you won't ever be able to access it by using `BlocProvider`.

> BlocBuilder handles building a widget in response to new states.
> BlocBuilder is analogous to StreamBuilder but has simplified API to
> reduce the amount of boilerplate code needed as well as bloc-specific
> performance improvements.

When you are using a `BlocBuilder` you will need to rely on the `state` value to access properties from your bloc or cubit and you will have to inject your bloc/cubit in the widget tree by using a parent `BlocProvider`, here's an example:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userCubit = UserCubit("firstName", "lastName");

    // Using BlocProvider to inject your UserCubit
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => userCubit,
      child: BlocBuilder<UserCubit, UserState>(
        // Still using the instance of userCubit as the injected instance is not
        // available in the widget tree at this point.
        bloc: userCubit,
        builder: (blocContext, state) {
          // Now that you are in your builder with an up-to-date blocContext you can
          // have access to your instance of UserCubit with BlocProvider.
          print(BlocProvider.of<UserCubit>(blocContext).user.fullName);
          return Text("State is $state");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[You can try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=24805273c2fefc9f11279109cd264716)